Why don’t closed wings eliminate tip vortices?
It’s clear that tip vortices never really can be prevented, but why doesn’t a closed wing do that? There is no ‘tip’ on a closed wing so where does the air go to make a vortex?
On a normal plane the air goes from the bottom surface to the top and curves around the wingtip, but what does it do in the case of a closed wing?

Closed wings are a bad idea anyway because the second wing as seen in the picture will probably create more drag than the tip vortices themselves.


I’ve also heard that a closed wing will have problems with boundary layer separation at the tips, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Related: Do box-wings suffer from induced drag the same way as normal wings?

@PeterKämpf Ah, interesting. It seems the box wing is basically the same thing as a closed wing as far as tip vortices go.

Also, if you see this @RobMcDonald, do you know why your answer was deleted? I was about to comment on it.

Find the fuel consumption and climb rate of that thing and compare it to a Piper Cub.

FYI, Rob deleted his own answer because it morphed into a discussion... (I guess you need a certain number of reputation points to see deleted answers)

@MichaelHall Ah I see. Thanks for informing me because I can't see the answer myself like you assumed.

@Wyatt Yes, I deleted it myself.

So, rivers of words have been written around this question but we don't have an answer, cool...

@sophit yeah there was an answer in the reply that got deleted, but since it got deleted you can’t see it anymore.

@Wyatt: yes I know, I can see that deleted answer. Still I don't understand why it simply doesn't get "streamlined" and undeleted since it is technically correct
